# Shorter way to convert Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>> to Result<Vec<T>, E>

Tags: rust, iterator

I have the following code converting from `Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>>` to `Result<Vec<T>, E>` but I'm wondering if there's something I don't know about iterators that could simplify it even more/make the code more concise.

```rust
fn clean<T, E>(data: Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    data.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|i| match i {
            Ok(Some(a)) => Some(Ok(a)),
            Ok(None) => None,
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        })
        .collect()
}
```

I was able to reduce it to this, but find the first example better since it does not have any `.unwrap()`:

```rust
fn clean<T, E>(data: Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    data.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|i| match i {
            Ok(None) => None,
            _ => Some(i.map(|i| i.unwrap())),
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it a lot shorter by using `transpose`:

```
fn clean<T, E>(data: Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    data.into_iter().filter_map(|i| i.transpose()).collect()
}
```

Or maybe you'd consider the point-free version cleaner:

```
fn clean<T, E>(data: Vec<Result<Option<T>, E>>) -> Result<Vec<T>, E> {
    data.into_iter().filter_map(Result::transpose).collect()
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this expresses the intent fairly well while being much less noisy.

Comment: That is what I was searching for, a shorter version, but still using iterators, thank you :)